# POST calls not reaching Controller, failing with 500

Tags: node.js, express, routes, http-post, kraken.js

In my KrakenJS Node App., I am Trying to test a controller functionality which ultimately does a POST call to a web server.

I am adding a new route in routes/index.js like below so that i can directly test it :

router.**post**('/testPost',  testController.testPostCall);

In this case when i try to call a POST on this URL via Rest Clients  ; the call does not even reach the controller & fails with 500 :

```
(t) URL TestNodeAPP_testPost
(E) LOG INFO
(A) RENDER errors_500  53ms
(T) URL TestNodeAPP_testPost  3391ms
**POST /TestNodeAPP/testPost 500** 3445.722 ms - 2738
```

But if i change the  router method to get like below, the call reaches the controller :

router.**get**('/testPost',  testController.testPostCall);

What needs to be done to make it work for POST call?

Comment: For POST to work, you need to do a POST call. Not just open the url in the browser. Try the "postman" extension for chrome - or similar tools

Comment: I tried changing the request type from GET to POST & then tried...Anyways, i tried via REST Clients too...will remove it from question..might be confusing :)

Comment: What's the error that you get

Comment: I updated the error in the question...